# loesung.charAt(i) gives Error: unexpected type expected: variable, found value

Tags: java

```
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    if(woerter[zahl].charAt(i) == tipp.charAt(0)){
        loesung.charAt(i) = tipp.charAt(0);
    }
}
```

I think i understand what a variable is and thought, "i" was one but appearantly it's a value. I have tried defining i at diefferent points in the code but the error won't go away. I'm new to coding and would love to know a solution to this problem.

Comment: No this has nothing to do with `i`. `loesung.charAt()` returns a value, you cannot use it on the left side of an assignment. Besides, you cannot overwrite a character in a String, since Strings are immutable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this method `loesung.charAt(i)` for getting char value at `index`, not for set value.

to change value of string at some index, you should do something like this

```
val chars = loesung.toCharArray()
chars[index] = newChar
loesung = String(chars)
```